# Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewPagerAdapter'

Tags: android

This line

```
 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Throws this error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewPagerAdapter'

Even though I have imported required library

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

And have compiled the right version

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
```

SO has many suggestion to resolve this error, but I believe I have attempted them all including rebuilding, cleaning, and invalidating caches and restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a class as `ViewPagerAdapter`.  Are you looking for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html))?

Comment: Thx. It's just a helper class.

Answer (score -3):

You should make a class named ViewPagerADAPTE

Comment: How it supposed to help? There is neither such android framework class `ViewPagerAdapter` nor `ViewPagerADAPTE`